# Sinatra sends damaged .zip file with `send_file` when I try to download with React

Tags: ruby, reactjs, zip, sinatra

So, in my Sinatra project I create a .zip file with some songs and then I want do return that file as a response with `send_file` helper. And when I try to download the file with React in front-end, it downloads something but it says that it is invalid format or damaged.

This is the code I have in Sinatra:

```rb
def download_songs(song_list)    
    time = Time.new
    temp_dir_name = rand(100000..999999).to_s + time.strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M%S")
    Dir.mkdir(temp_dir_name)
    song_list.each { |song|
        formatted_command = 'youtube-dl -o "' + __dir__.to_s + '/' + temp_dir_name + '/%(title)s.%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 "ytsearch:' + song + '"'
        system formatted_command
    }

    zipfile_name = "#{__dir__.to_s}/#{temp_dir_name}/YourSongs.zip"
    folder_to_zip = "#{__dir__.to_s}/#{temp_dir_name}"
    file_names = Dir.children(temp_dir_name)

    Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
        file_names.each do |filename|
            zipfile.add(filename, File.join(folder_to_zip, filename))
        end
    end    

    file_to_send_to_front = "./" + temp_dir_name + "/YourSongs.zip"
    send_file file_to_send_to_front, :filename => "YourSongs.zip", :type => 'application/octet-stream'
end
```

And I call that function in this piece of code:

```rb
post '/download' do
    content_type :json
    all_songs_to_download = params['songs'].split(',')
    download_songs(all_songs_to_download)        
end
```

And when it downloads it locally on the server. I can open it normaly, so I would say that Zip is not being created incorrectly, but that React is downloading it wrongly or `send_file` is sending it in a wrong way. Btw I tried to send a normal `README.md` file the same way and it worked fine.

And this is code in React I use to download the .zip file:

```js
_downloadSongs = () => {

        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('songs', this.state.songs);

        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:4567/download',
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        }).then(res => {
            fileDownload(res.data, 'YourSongs.zip');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

**NOTE**: I am using [js-file-download](https://github.com/kennethjiang/js-file-download) to download the file I recieve as response from Sinatra.

Comment: Tip: Consider using `SecureRandom.uuid` for "random name" type stuff. Using a narrow range like that can lead to collisions due to the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: @tadman Thanks for that tip a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting the following in `send_file` :

```
:type => 'application/zip',
:disposition => 'attachment'
```

Comment: It's usually better to express with modern Ruby notation: `type: '...'` in preference to the ancient 1.8 style `:type => '...'`.

Comment: While it is useful to point out the newer syntax, it is hard justify that it is "better" other than as a matter of opinion.

Comment: It'll be consistent with most Ruby code-bases written in the last five years, and it's also immediately familiar to people who use other languages like JavaScript where the notation is identical. Above all else, it's also less typing.